# I am working on IP create in form and want explode some data

Tags: php, laravel

It's my store method where I am getting IP through request from my view

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $ip['ip_range'] = $request->input('ip_range');
        $ip['min_ip']   = $request->input('ip_range');
        $ip['max_ip']   = $request->input('ip_range');

        $ip_data = Ip::create($ip);
        session()->flash('msg', ' Successfully created');
        return view('ip.index');
    }
```

In above I want if IP comes as

**192.168.2.9**
**192.168.1.2**

It should be saved as 2 values .... Mean it should separate it on `/r/n` and where I found `/n` I create a new value and so on.

And next thing is that if user enter as

**192.168.1.0-3**

Here a `-` comes at last one `192.168.1-3` should be save in **ip_range** and `192.168.1.0` in **min_ip** while `192.168.1.3` as **max_ip**.

Comment: You are asking for code.. do something yourself and consult.

Comment: Some pointers for you
1. `filter_var($request->input('ip_range'), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)` can be used to validate a single IP - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
2. `preg_match("/\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}(\r\n)*/", $request->input('ip_range'))` can be used to check if there are multiple addresses and if there are, `explode('\r\n', $request->input('ip_range'))` can be used to get them.
3. `preg_match("/\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[-]\d{1,3}(\r\n)*/", $request->input('ip_range'))` can be used to check for a range

Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $ip['ip_range'] = $request->input('ip_range');

    $arrIps = explode("\r\n", $ip['ip_range']);
    foreach($arrIps as $strIp) {

        $arrRange=explode("-",$strIp);
        if(count($arrRange)>1){
         $ip['min_ip']= $arrRange[0];
         $arrDot=explode(".",$arrRange[0]);
         $arrDot[3]=$arrRange[1];
         $ip['max_ip']= implode(".",$arrDot);
        }
        else
        $ip['min_ip']=$ip['max_ip']="";

        $ip_data = Ip::create($ip);

    }
    session()->flash('msg', ' Successfully created');
    return view('ip.index');
}
```

Comment: its very close one problem is now occur its saving as this `192.168.1.0-20 192.168.1.0-20 ` in 'ip_range' it should save only one in one field

Comment: these are 2 ips in one field it should only one in ist and 2nd will be in in 2nd row

Comment: and also in 1st case it is saving as 192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1 only in 1st field not in min and max columns